# Meaning of "Vanity is the greatest seducer of reason"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I was reading Meditation by Marcus. I do not understand this part:

> Vanity is the greatest seducer of reason: when you are most convinced that your work is important, that is when you are most under its spell. See, for example, what Creates says even about Xenocrates.

Can some please explain this paragraph?  I got the overall meaning but not *seducer of reason*.

Comment: Please indicate which parts are hanging you up.

Comment: @aparente001 I got the overall meaning. But did not get context of `seducer of reason`

Comment: If you know what a *seducer* is, and you know what *reason* is, the meaning should be apparent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Marcus Aurelius, in Chapter 6 of his *Meditations*, is quoting a (now lost) saying by Crates, the Greek Cynic philosopher, about Xenocrates (another Greek philosopher), to the effect that if you are vain and self-important, you will be likely to deceive yourself.  See [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dVA2PUxNn9sC&pg=PT281&lpg=PT281&dq=Crates%20says%20even%20about%20Xenocrates.&source=bl&ots=gIMqkFSj1-&sig=yAIARrOVhYPhnavZbGedY_Ud0Fg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjEh7CxjLrUAhVEI8AKHfcAD6YQ6AEIPTAF#v=onepage&q=Crates%20says%20even%20about%20Xenocrates.&f=false).